# Trying to understand a line of my own code regarding nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

Please go to: [my website](http://www.ryanteaches.com) here. Then hover over "GCSEs" and then over "maths". You will see that when you hover over maths, or geography, another "sub-menu" appears with dropdown content "algebra" etc.. I am trying to make the sub-menu horizontally inline with the parent.

Here is the css code of the sub menu:

```css
/*-------------- Second sub menu -----------*/
.dropdown2 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown2 .dropbtn2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  height: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

/*--- Colour when hovered over ---*/ 
.redhover a:hover,
.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* --- Colour of background of box when parent is hovered over but sub content is NOT hovered over --- */
.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 margin-left: 160px; 
}

/* --- Text formatting of sub-content --- */
.dropdown-content2 a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

/*--- Colour of background box when hovering over sub content ----*/
.dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/*----- affects size of sub content block ---*/
.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 { 
  display: block;
}

/*-----------End of sub menu -------------*/
```

Which line, is the line that currently sets the "dropdown content" e.g. Algebra etc. "below" the parent? Looking through my code, I am not sure how I ever managed to get my dropdown content to appear below the button.

If I can figure out what is making it appear below the parent, I should be able to figure out how to move it horizontally inline. I have already move the dropdown content the correct distance to the "right" of the parent, but its set below.

cheers!

Comment: Please ensure your question contains all relevant code, images and information without needing to go to your website. Otherwise, as soon as your website changes the question is of no use to anyone in the future if it is needed to understand the issue. - If possible, it helps if you can add a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question to demonstrate the issue in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `margin-top value` of `-44px` to `dropdown-content2` will achieve this, although it might not be the most effective solution.

```
.dropdown-content2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
margin-left: 160px;
margin-top: -44px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - I have done that, it works perfectly. Now (if you click link again and see menu) you see when you move across to the sub-menu, I want the "parent" to stay highlighted in the darker colour. How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: I've had a look now, and it already seems to do that - assume you've got that working now

Answer (score 0):

Add **margin-top:-45px;** style in dropdown-content2 class.It should work.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you didn't do anything for it, but as long as the dropdown has no left or top position, and is after the button, it works.

Be careful with that, it could be a problem with some older browsers.

Usually I set a `position: relative` to the parent element then for the dropdown element `left:0; top: <menu-height>`